# React Js pulling variable from another top level component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

so i have my two different views one with search on it and then after you select the data row you want it changes to the view base which shows you all the data in full. only thing is you have to be logged in to view it but when you change the url it doesnt carry over the logged in value to make it true so it logs you out and your still able to view the data how would i make it carry the data over from the first page to the second one.

```
doSomething(value) {
    this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: value
    }, function () {
        this.state.isLoggedIn
    })
    if (this.state.isLoggedIn === false) {
        this.setState({
            searchResults: []
        }, function () {
            this.state.searchResults
        })

    }
}
```

that is what sets the state of isLoggedIn on the first page how would i pass the variable through to the second page as its not a child or any relation to this component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `redux` and create a global store to manage state

Comment: yeah thanks completely over though this lol. need to start intergrating redux from the get go

Comment: check other libraries also like `mobx`, but redux is most popular

Comment: would i call my global store from inside my do something function